# Problem with @story = Story.find(params[:story_id]) in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have an app  that I have recently upgraded to rails 3

In my comments controller I have

```
def create
  @cuser = @current_user   
  @story = Story.find(params[:story_id]) 
  @story.comments.create(:user_id => @cuser.login,:body => params[:comment][:body])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { story_path}
    format.js
  end
end
```

In `story.rb`  I have  `has_many :comments`
In `comment.rb` I have `belongs_to :story`

When I try to create a comment I get a

```
Couldn't find Story without an ID
```

This used to work. Any ideas why it doesn't any more ? What else could be affecting it? Could it be a routing issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your form definition should look like this:

```
<%= form_for [@story, Comment.new] do |form| %> 
  <div id="body"> 
    <%= form.text_field :body %> 
  </div> <% form.hidden_field :user_id, :value => @current_user.login %> 
  <p>
    <%= submit_tag 'Comment' %>
  </p> 
<% end %>
```

Your form uses `POST /comments` instead of `POST /stories/:story_id/comments` action.
It should have thrown an exception about a missing `POST /comments` route, that's why I wasn't sure about my solution. But your routes have the `comments` resources for some reason. So it knows how to create the URL, but it doesn't know it should include the `/stories/:story_id` part.

Another thing here is you pass current_user with the form. It's bad since anyone who knows how to use firebug or any other web-master tools can change this field to, say, your login and post comments as if it were you. You should assign the user field in your create action of the controller.

And one more. I really can't see why you would need all this routes. If it was my app, routes would look something like this:

```
Telling_tales::Application.routes.draw do 

  resource :session 
  resource :stories #really can't see why you need a singular route here 
  resource :user 
  resources :users do
    get 'register' => 'create', :on => :collection #maps to 'users#create'
  end

  resources :stories do 
    resources :comments
    collection do
      get ':login' => 'show' #it seems illogical to place this route under `stories` namespace 
                            #if you wanted to display stories of one particular user, you'd better make it `/users/:user_id/stories`
      get 'search'
  end
  root :to => 'stories#index' 
end
```

Take a look at [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) and [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) guides.

Comment: I am using params[:story_id] now. It makes no difference

Comment: @gleb - can we see the form where this is from.  I think that bassneck is on to something.  Maybe story_id is never passed in the form.

Comment: This is the form

<%= form_for Comment.new do |form| %>
       <div id="body">
           <%= form.text_field :body %>
       </div>
       <% form.hidden_field  :user_id, :value => @current_user.login %>
       
       <p><%= submit_tag  'Comment' %></p>
<% end %>

Comment: This is routes.rb

Telling_tales::Application.routes.draw do
  match '/' => 'stories#index'
  resources :stories
  match 'story/:login' => 'story#show'
  match 'story/:search' => 'story#search'
  resource :session
  resources :comments
  resource :stories
  resource :user
  resources :users
  match 'users/:register' => 'users#register'
       
  resources :stories do  
      resources :comments
  end

Comment: @gleb Add the form by editing your question. Comments do not support readable code. =)

Comment: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"stories"} comes up if I use [@story, Comment.new]

Comment: It is a bigger with many controllers the cooment it is only part of it, that's whhy the extra routes. They were generated by  rails-upgrade

Comment: <%= form_for [@stories, Comment.new] do |form| %>  Did it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

yes, it can be a routing issue.  You have probably spotted that the routing dsl has changed, and I guess you are messing around with it.  Looks like you used to have a route something like

`map.resources :stories

and you have (maybe) replaced that with something like

```
    resources :stories do 
      resources :comments do
        collection  do
          post :create
        end 
      end  
    end
```

I'm only guessing , but I think this would give the sort of error you are seeing - you need a route like

```
resources :stories do
  resources :comments
end
```

which will automatically generate the create route, or if you want to specify it more precisely

```
resources :stories do
  resources :comments do
    member do
      post :create
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I do have resources :stories do
  resources :comments
end

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have the following route-configuration:

```
resources :stories do
  resources :comments
end
```

If that's the case, you have to use `params[:story_id]`.

```
@story = Story.find(params[:story_id])
```

Comment: I am using params[:story_id] now but it doesn't help